# How to get quantity of each product in cart magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, qty

After added products to cart, we can get all qty in cart. But I want to get qty of each product, how to do? Thanks.

[image]

This is my cart I added product. I want to get qty of each product, example: product 1( item 1 and 2) qty = 4

Comment: do you want qty on cart page  i.e in phtml ?

Comment: Usually magento doesn't add same product twice, like in your screenshot. By default Magento will always increase the qty on "add to cart", if product is already in cart.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri My product is buy 1 get 1 free, so it will be add twice

Comment: @Pawan hmm, yes...

Comment: please try: <?php $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote(); 
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        echo $qty = $this->escapeHtml($item->getQty());
    } ?>

Comment: @Pawan So how can I get the only qty of product 1 for check condition? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: You can check my updated answer.

Comment: If issue solved then please accept and upvote answer. So, other user can use this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I use this code:

```
        $sku = find_your_product_sku;
        $sum =0;
        $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();

        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product = array (
                'id' => $item->getSku(),
                'quantity' => $item->getQty()
            );
            if ($product['id']==$sku) {
                $sum += $product['quantity'];
            }
        }
```

Thanks Rohan and Pawan for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You can get product quantity like this :

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$product = [];

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product[]= array (
                'id' => $item->getSku(),
                'quantity' => $item->getQty()
        );
}

$product_json = json_encode($product);
```

For get qty of specific product :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
$qty = $_item->getQty();
```